# Conditional comment in XSL not working

Tags: internet-explorer, xslt, conditional-comments

I have added a conditional comment in XSL like

```
 <xsl:comment>          
    <![CDATA[
       [if IE]>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             registerDisplay = firstChild.currentStyle.display;
         </script>
       <![endif]            
     ]]>
 </xsl:comment>
```

I'm not seeing this my html source in IE. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This works fine for me when run with xsltproc (though you probably want to remove the white space between the comment tags and the conditional stuff, i.e. `<xsl:comment><![CDATA[[if IE]` and `<![endif]]]></xsl:comment>`).  Remember that when you open an XML file with an `<?xml-stylesheet` instruction in a browser, view source will give you the original XML, not the HTML that results from the XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're unlucky with the xsl:comment, I think alternatively you could use

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<!--[if IE]>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         registerDisplay = firstChild.currentStyle.display;
     </script>
   <![endif]-->]]>
</xsl:text>
```